# How is quantile estimator constructed?

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, sampling, quantiles

It is a popular practice to check if the random sample comes from a specific probability distribution by plotting a *quantile-quantile* figure.
For a finite sample one can only use an **estimator** of a quantile. How is it constructed? It is biased/unbiased? What is the approximate sampling distribution and confidence interval?

Comment: You may find this article helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: @Kodiologist I had a look at the implementation in R and there are a few different non-parametric estimators of quantiles (all based on order statistics).